# Intellij Idea | Как убрать отображение параметров в методах

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: target, name]

**target, name**
 Как это можно убрать?

Answer (score 4):

1. В редакторе нажимаем <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
2. Убираем галочку с Editor -> Appearance -> Show parameter name hints

Answer (score 0):

В новой версии Idea

**MainMenu > File > Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints > Paramter Names > "Ваш язык программирования"**